# $5$-th power of a complex matrix is identity. What are the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a complex matrix satisfying: $A^5=I$ What are the possible (complex) eigenvalues of $A$?

Don't really have any ideas. Can we say that $\det(A)=1$ ? if so does it help at all?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about using this: if $p$ is a polynomial and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$,

Comment: @GEdgar: While that is true, the statement somewhat obscures what is going on. I find it easier to remember and understand that $P[A]$ acts on an eigenspace of$~A$ for eigenvalue$~\lambda$ by the scalar $P[\lambda]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $Au=\lambda u$ (with $u\not=0$) then $0=(A^5-I)u=(\lambda^5-1) u$.

What may we conclude about the eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Comment: That would mean \lambda are the fifth roots of unity? But how did you get $(A^5-I)u=(\lambda^5-1)u$

Comment: @Kevin Yeh Because $A^2u=A(Au)=A(\lambda u)=\lambda A u=\lambda(\lambda u)=\lambda^2 u$ and so on.

Comment: @Kevin Yeh Any further doubt?

Comment: No, all is clear. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $X^5-1$ is annihilator of $A$, therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are fifth roots of the unity. Please note, that not all fifth roots of the unity are necessarily eigenvalues of $A$, this is only an inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of the Eigendecomposition,

$$A=P^{-1}DP$$ so that

$$A^5=P^{-1}DPP^{-1}DPP^{-1}DPP^{-1}DPP^{-1}DP=P^{-1}D^5P=I$$ and $D^5=I$.

This shows that the Eigenvalues are fifth roots of the unit.

Comment: You're assuming that $A$ is diagonalizable without justification

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: that's right.